# How is the Prékopa Leindler inequality different from Holder's inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, holder-inequality

The following is an extract from [these notes (Pg. 30)](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf), and I'm not able to understand the part towards the end. I would appreciate any help!

> **Prékopa-Leindler Inequality:** Let $f$, $g$ and $m$ be non-negative measurable functions on $\mathbb R^n$, $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$,
> \begin{equation}
>     m(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq f(x)^{\lambda}g(y)^{1-\lambda}.
> \end{equation}
> Then,
> $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} m \geq \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}f\right)^\lambda \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}g\right)^{1-\lambda}$$
> It is perhaps helpful to notice that the Prékopa–Leindler inequality looks like
> Hölder’s inequality, backwards. If $f$ and $g$ were given and we set $$m(z) = f(z)^{1-\lambda} g(z)^\lambda$$
> (for each $z$), then Hölder’s inequality says that $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} m \leq \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}f\right)^{1-\lambda} \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}g\right)^{\lambda}$$
> (Hölder’s inequality is often written with $1/p$ instead of $1 − λ$, $1/q$ instead of
> $λ$, and $f , g$ replaced by $F^p , G^q$ .) **The difference between Prékopa–Leindler and
> Hölder is that, in the former, the value $m(z)$ may be much larger since it is a
> supremum over many pairs $(x, y)$ satisfying $z = (1 − λ)x + λy$ rather than just
> the pair $(z, z)$.**

Could someone please explain the part in bold? I don't understand the part where the author talks about the suprema over pairs $(x,y)$ and $(z,z)$ in the two cases. Lastly, what's $F^p, G^q$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In favour of symmetry, I've switched $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ in the Hölder's inequality you have stated.
Hölder's inequality says that given non-negative functions $f$ and $g$, if we define $$m(z)=f(z)^\lambda g(z)^{1-\lambda}$$
for each $z$,
$$\int m \leq \left(\int f\right)^\lambda \left(\int g\right)^{1-\lambda}.$$

In the Prékopa-Leindler Inequality on the other hand, each $m(z)$ is bounded below by some parameter depending on all the $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ for points $x$,$y$ satisfying $z=\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$.
Since the inequality is a lower bound on the integral of $m$, the worst-case scenario is when $m$ attains the minimum possible value at every point, which is the supremum that is mentioned. That is, if we define
$$m(z)=\sup_{\substack{x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n \\ z=\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y}} f(x)^\lambda g(y)^{1-\lambda}$$
for each $z$ (even for any general $m$ satisfying the condition, $m(z)$ must be at least the quantity above),
$$\int m\geq \left(\int f\right)^\lambda \left(\int g\right)^{1-\lambda}.$$

Comparing the definition of $m$ in the two inequalities, it is seen that we only take the pair $(x,y)=(z,z)$ in Hölder's inequality.
The two inequalities are rather similar in terms of basic structure, but also quite different due to the supremum involved in the Prékopa-Leindler inequality, which causes the direction of the inequality to be reversed.

> Lastly, what's $F^p$,$G^q$?

Hölder's inequality usually isn't stated in the format the author (and I) have stated it above. In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) which contains the "usual" statement of the theorem, it is given as

> Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $p, q \in [1, \infty)$ with $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Then, for all measurable real- or complex-valued functions $F$ and $G$ on $S$,
> $$\|FG\|_1 ≤ \|F\|_p \|G\|_q. $$

The equivalence of this and the statement described in the notes is seen on writing $f=F^p$, $g=G^q$, and $1/p=\lambda$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what $\|F\|_p$ is defined to be? I'd guess $$\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} (F(\mathbf x))^p d\mathbf x\right)^{1/p}$$ from the context.
If not, what is it? and where does this norm originate (perhaps in inner products)?

Comment: Also, I think you want to say *"...the worst-case scenario is when $m$ attains the **maximum** possible value at every point..."*, instead of **minimum**?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Yes, your definition of $\|F\|_p$ is correct, except that we use $|F|$ in the integral instead of $F$. $L^p$ spaces and $\mathcal{L}^p$ spaces are quite important in general, and googling should give you several results.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor No, I meant what I wrote. We have the inequality $m(z) \geq \sup_{x,y : z = \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y} f(x)^{\lambda} g(y)^{1-\lambda}$. This bound is attained when $m(z)$ is the minimum value allowed by this inequality, which is the supremum involved in the right hand side.

Comment: Ah, got it. It's probably just a difference in perspective, right? I was thinking of it as "maximum" since it's a *supremum* over the RHS, for the fixed point $z$.

Comment: Yeah maybe, I wrote "minimum" because that is the minimum possible value of $m(z)$, and that given $f$ and $g$ I am choosing a particular $m$.